# Eclipse Device Screen Capture using Rezound has black band on right

Tags: android, eclipse, screen-capture

In Eclipse on the DDMS tab if I do a device screen capture with an HTC Rezound, I always get a picture with a black band on the right side of the screen (see below).
No other phone that I have tried has this issue and I suspect that it is due to the 720p display on this phone.
Any ideas on how I can get a good screen capture using this phone?
Thanks!

[image]